# How to get variable value from Entry tkinter python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI with tkinter. I was able to setup the interface, with buttons, labels etc. However, when I type a string or int in the interface (using Entry, but also with combobox and chekcbutton) the assigned varible doesn't appear if try to print it, I only got printed the following instead of the variable values:

.!entry, .!entry2, .!combobox, .!checkbutton

Does anybody know how to fix it?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from tkinter import filedialog

def browse_button1():
    global folder_path
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    folder_path1.set(filename)
def browse_button2():
   global folder_path
   filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
   folder_path2.set(filename) 

main_window = Tk()
folder_path1 = StringVar()
folder_path2 = StringVar()
var = StringVar()
def1 = StringVar(main_window, value='Sharp')

# Labels
Label(main_window, text= "Folder Path").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
Label(main_window, text= "Scan File").grid(row = 1, column = 0)

#Text Input
e1 = Entry(main_window, width= 50, borderwidth= 5, textvariable= folder_path1)
e1.grid(row= 0, column= 1, columnspan= 2, sticky="we", pady=10)
e2 = Entry(main_window, width= 50, borderwidth= 5, textvariable= folder_path2)
e2.grid(row= 1, column= 1, columnspan= 2, sticky="we", pady=10)

#Combobox list
var.set("Sharp")
data = ("Sharp", "Intermediate", "Standard", "Soft")
cb = Combobox(main_window, values=data, textvariable= def1)
cb.grid(row=4, column= 1, sticky = 'w', pady=10)

#Checkbutton
cbu = Checkbutton(main_window)
cbu.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky = 'w', pady=10)

def on_click():
    print(f"{e1}, {e2}, {cb}, {cbu}")
    
#Buttons
Button(main_window, text= "Run", command = on_click, width = 25).grid(row= 8, column= 1, columnspan= 2, sticky="we", pady=10)
Button(main_window, text= "Browse", command = browse_button1, width = 12).grid(row= 0, column= 3)
Button(main_window, text= "Browse", command = browse_button2, width = 12).grid(row= 1, column= 3)

main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: cb = Combobox(main_window, values=data, textvariable= def1)
NameError: name 'def1' is not defined

Comment: my mistake in cutting the code to create this post, in the original script def1 is defined. The original script is longer but I cut it to focus only on the question. I corrected the post :)

Comment: You are printing the widgets themselves not their values/content, so please read some tutorials/documentation about tkinter, e.g. https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html, I am sure you will find how to get the values of the various widgets. Tip: you need to call one of the widget's methods.

Comment: @Giorgio Luongo. print(f"{e1.get()}, {e2.get()}, {cb.get()}")

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.get()` method to retrieve widget values. Simply change:

```
def on_click():
    print(f"{e1}, {e2}, {cb}, {cbu}")
```

to:

```
# create a variable to store the Checkbutton state
cb_var = StringVar()
# update 'cbu' to use that variable
cbu = Checkbutton(main_window, variable=cb_var)


def on_click():
    print(f"{e1.get()}, {e2.get()}, {cb.get()}, {cb_var.get()}")
```

Comment: Note that `Checkbutton` does not have `.get()`, so `cbu.get()` is invalid.

Comment: @acw1668 You're absolutely right - I've edited my answer. Thanks for the heads-up!